# How to use compression for "state" column in "jv snapshot" table to reduce DB size?

Tags: java, mysql, javers

We use MySQL DB to store javers data. We have many rows in "jv_snapshot" table, so we want to reduce DB size. Will be fine if javers persists "state" column as compressed JSON.
Is it possible?
What can we do to reduce javers snapshot data size?

Comment: Will be fine if Javers will provide possibility to set Custom Serializer and Custom Deserializer to convert "state" column data before persist and before read operation.
In this case we can do data compression if needed.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

There is no compression option for now. It can be quite easily implemented in JaversSqlRepository. JSON with Snapshot state could be compressed with gzip. We will accept a pull request if you are eager to contribute.